# what is a slang for "become a new person"

Tags: expressions, translation

I'm looking for an expression or slang for "becoming a new person, forget the things you knew, restart fresh" or something near these.

I'm doing a translation from Persian to English and the literal translation is "coming out of your grave"
like your thoughts and believes are like grave and to be alive you have to let go.

Comment: All of those are idiomatic and informal English; you need to decide which one is suitable for your needs. It helps if you can describe the context in which you are seeking these terms, preferably without relying on the reader knowing any Persian (Farsi?).

Comment: TNX, the context is also in Persian :(((

Comment: If you could tell us the literal translation, as close as you can manage, of the original phrase and the sentence it appears in that would be helpful. It doesn't need to be a "good" translation, just enough to give us a sense of the context--for instance, whether it's a casual conversation or a bit of philosophical poetry or an academic treatise, whether you want a term that is positive, negative, or neutral, and so forth.

Comment: Well it literally means "to get out of your grave" and the meaning is the things you think you know are wrong and they won't let you to understand the truth you have to put them aside, they are like a grave you have to get out of it if you want to be alive.

Comment: For those familiar with "Irregular Verbs" from the _Yes, Minister_ TV show,  there is ... I am going through a rebirthing process -/- you are having a mid-life crisis -/- he is totally losing the plot.

Comment: For those unfamiliar, the joke is someone using totally different words to describe identical behaviours - depending on who they are taking about.

Answer (score 1):

***Turning over a new leaf*** is an idiomatic English expression for making a fresh start and trying to improve:

> To make a change for the better especially in one's way of living
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20over%20a%20new%20leaf)*</sub>
>
> Make a fresh start, change one's conduct or attitude for the better
>   <sub>*from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+over+a+new+leaf)*</sub>

Comment: This is absolutely the most common way to say this.

Comment: ...followed _closely_ by "starting fresh" or "making a fresh start".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin — "starting afresh" is the more common ideom. "starting fresh" can just mean getting to work after a good night's sleep. But it does not have all the implications of "turning over a new leaf".